# Setting a complex default value in QGIS 3.30 that does not update automatically

Tags: qgis, expression, formula

I'm currently using QGIS 3.30 and I'm trying to set a default value for a field based on multiple other fields, without having the default value update automatically whenever an attribute of the feature is updated. The expression I'm using is as follows:

```
CASE
  WHEN count("AID") = 0 THEN
    regexp_replace(
      upper(
        concat(
          coalesce(left(rpad("vorname", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
          coalesce(left(rpad("name", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
          coalesce(left(rpad("rolle", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),

          lpad('1', 4, '0'),
          @nis_project_id
        )
      ),
      '[^a-zA-Z0-9]',
      '_'
    )
  ELSE
    regexp_replace(
      upper(
        concat(
          coalesce(left(rpad("vorname", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
          coalesce(left(rpad("name", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
          coalesce(left(rpad("rolle", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
          lpad(
            to_string(
              maximum(to_int(substr("AID", 4, 4))) + 1
            ),
            4,
            '0'
          ),
          @nis_project_id
        )
      ),
      '[^a-zA-Z0-9]',
      '_'
    )
END
```

The goal is to generate an ID based on the values of other fields when a new feature is created, but not to have the ID change if the feature is updated.

When I set the 'Apply default value on update' option, the ID is generated as expected, but also updates every time an attribute of the feature changes, which is not what I want.

When I do not set the 'Apply default value on update' option, the ID is not generated correctly when I input a new feature. It seems to ignore the values of other fields that are supposed to be used in generating the ID.

Could anyone guide me on how to set the default value based on the expression above, such that it considers the values of other fields at the time of feature creation and does not update automatically with each feature update?

Edit: Even with unchecked "edidable" it's still updating: [image]

New Edit: I want the AID to be updated while the user is typing:

[image]

Here is a siplyfied test-project:
[Test-Project](https://www.map-site.de/tmp/NIS-AID-Test.zip)

Comment: Wait... why do you even need to have 'Apply default value on update' checked if you only want the ID to be generated on feature create? The default expression should still work as long as you are creating a new feature. When I have generated auto incrementing ID fields I always have 'Apply default value on update' unchecked....

Comment: The answer is: I would like the generated ID to be displayed while the user is filling out the form.

Comment: I added a new screen record to my question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check if the id-variable is negative (at feature creation) and modify your expression so it calculates the value for the column AID only as long as @id is negative:

**( 'Apply default value on update' option activated )**

```
 CASE WHEN @id <0 THEN
 
    CASE
      WHEN count("AID") = 0 THEN
        regexp_replace(
          upper(
            concat(
              coalesce(left(rpad("vorname", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
              coalesce(left(rpad("name", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
              coalesce(left(rpad("rolle", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),

              lpad('1', 4, '0'),
              @nis_project_id
            )
          ),
          '[^a-zA-Z0-9]',
          '_'
        )
      ELSE
        regexp_replace(
          upper(
            concat(
              coalesce(left(rpad("vorname", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
              coalesce(left(rpad("name", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
              coalesce(left(rpad("rolle", 1, 'X'), 3), 'X'),
              lpad(
                to_string(
                  maximum(to_int(substr("AID", 4, 4))) + 1
                ),
                4,
                '0'
              ),
              @nis_project_id
            )
          ),
          '[^a-zA-Z0-9]',
          '_'
        )
    END

ELSE "AID"

END
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. I don't know why, but after changing the expression, the AID isn't built up anymore from "name", "vorname", and "roll". Only the number updates.

Comment: @MartinMap: Do you have a test-dataset? Is "@nis_project_id" a project variable ?

Comment: Yes, it's a project variable. I added a siplyfied test project to my question...

Comment: Can you try it with   CASE WHEN @id <0 THEN  (see answer updated )

Comment: YES! that's it!

Comment: Fantastic answer, I think I might try this out for QField as well.

Answer (score 1):

As you remarked correctly, the `default-value` checkbox needs to be checked, otherwise feature generation doesn't work.

If you uncheck the `editable` checkbox at the top of your attributes form, the ID wont change when you edit the feature.

[image]

Comment: Sounds simple and nice, but it doesn't work. Also, when "editable" is unchecked, the field is still updating.

Comment: Seems like "update" means "updating the attribute table", but not "moving the feature". I only checked the latter.

Comment: just one idea for a workaround: does it work if you
a: check apply default value on update 
b: first check if the AID column is still empty and only then apply your logic? 

CASE WHEN AIS IS NULL 

THEN 

... your expression ...

END

I guess in this case the desired behaviour for the initial filling of the coulumn would work and would not be changed by other attribute updates... for sure just a workaround but perhaps it helps

Comment: @ThomasB feel free to add this as an answer, since it seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try a python function that returns a value indicating whether the record is being created or updated - something like this:

```
from qgis.core import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_record_status(feature, parent):
    if feature.id() < 0:
       return 'Created'
    else:
       return 'Updated'
```

Edit the expression for the the ID default value so that it calls this function and generates the ID field if the returned value is 'Created' using the case statement you have already written. If the returned value is 'Updated' do nothing.